# Drawables of main project are not picked up by library project in android

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I have two projects where

apps project
|----> depends on Library project

I have an icon(a.png) and layout(b.xml) in library project. I copied a new iconwith the same name a.png and the same layout(b.xml) which is from the library project into apps project then the application is picking the new icon(a.png, a modified one).

I deleted the layout(b.xml) file from apps projects as there is no code change, just the icon is changed. Now the application is not picking the new a.png file which is a modified one in apps, it is still showing the one from library project.

Is there a way to ask/push the layout present in library project to pick the a.png from apps project?

I'm supposed to copy the layout and paste it in the apps project for to pick the new a.png file.

Comment: Did you try using "clean" option for your project as well as restarting Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, tried this but not working.

Comment: Try removing everything from `bin` folder in your project.

Comment: @RushabhPatel Did you even read his problem description? He's not getting any error.